# Share pager among multiple jqgrid

Tags: jquery, pager

I have a table with 50 columns. I want to display the records using jqgrid. Since jqgrid width was too large so i break table into four logical groups and put under four tabs in separate jqgrid. I want to make one pager for all jqgrid because all jqgrid displaying the records of same table. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think that jqgrid may use the same pager for all jqGrids on the same page.  You just have to use the "pager" option in the grid definition.  For example if you have you pager div element like this:

```
<div id="my_pager"></div>
```

Then in your jqGrid definition it will look something like this:

```
$("#label_edit").jqGrid({
    url:'some_url',
    pager: '#my_pager',
});
```

You add pager:"#my_pager" to each jqgrid where you want to use this same pager.

Most likely you will have many more options besides "url" and "pager". This is just an examples.